# Linq удалить диапазон по id

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

Как написать запрос удаления диапазона по списку id, без создания сущностей которые требуются в RemoveRange?

Comment: Под id подразумевается индексы элементов или поле объектов в коллекции?

Comment: У вас Entity Framework или что?

Comment: У меня EF. Id индексы в бд.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Решил вопрос таким образом (через фейковые объекты):

```
    public async Task DeleteUsersByIdAsync(IEnumerable<Int32> id_users)
    {
        using (REMOTE_OFFICE_3Entities db = new REMOTE_OFFICE_3Entities())
        {
            IEnumerable<User> delete_users = id_users
                .Select(selector: id => new User { id = id })
                .Select(selector: read => db.Users.Attach(entity: read));

            db.Users.RemoveRange(entities: delete_users);
            await db.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
    }
```

Comment: `.Select(selector: read => db.Users.Attach(entity: read))` выглядит не очень, лучше переписать на обычный `foreach`. Но в целом подход верный.

Comment: @АндрейNOP, да как вариант, ну тут уж на вкус и цвет :)

Comment: Конкретно этот `Select` плох тем, что он ленивый и выполнится уже внутри `RemoveRange`. Стоит изменить чуть-чуть код (через полгода возникнет потребность) и всё сломается и вы будете разбираться почему. Оно вам надо? Ну и семантически Linq не предназначен для изменения (тем более сторонних сущностей), он предназначен для запросов. Кому нужны эти побочные эффекты? Не нужно пытаться вместить в одну строчку кода как можно больше работы, лучше разделить ее на две, но с конкретной задачей каждая.

Comment: Тот же принцип единственной ответственности: Сформировали коллекцию User на основе их Id; Приаттачили всех юзеров; Удалили; Сохранили. Зачем объединять несвязанные действия в одно...

Comment: Builder + текучий интерфейс (@JonSkeet c# in depth 10.4.2) повышает читаемость кода. Ну а заставить выполнить до RemoveRange можно например вот так: delete_users.ToArray();

Comment: Боюсь, вы превратно поняли Скита. В любом случае, не мне вас учить :)

Comment: @АндрейNOP, не исключаю что вы правы, поставлю плюсики вашим комментам :)

Comment: @ИванК очень странно переживать за читабельность кода, и при этом называть переменные read, писать в инициализации `{ id = id }` и зачем-то явно указывать имена всех параметров (даже в тех местах, где параметр ровно один)

Comment: @ИванК я к тому, что весь ваш код отлично сокращается до трех строк. `var users = id_users.Select(id => new User { id }).ToList(); db.Users.AttachRange(users); db.Users.RemoveRange(users);`. Это в полтора раза короче, чем хитрое колдовство с селектами.

Comment: @PashaPash, признаю о существовании метода AttachRange я и не подозревал...  переменная read - остаток от переделки реального метода в конкретный пример. Именованные параметры сильно улучшают читаемость кода при кол-ве параметров начиная с 2-3, кроме того предотвращают глупые ошибки с перепутыванием мест, поэтому это политика нашей группы и отсутствие их настроено как warn в VS , я даже уже не замечаю что использую их это стало как то естественно.

Comment: @ИванК ох уж эти политики групп :)

Comment: @PashaPash, "именованные аргументы в
некоторых ситуациях могут выглядеть странными, пока вы не привыкнете к ним" (Дж.Скит) Да я люблю его цитировать :) А в целом ваш пример мне нравится, плюсанул

Comment: @ИванК Вот вам три последних ответа Скита: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49789522/, https://stackoverflow.com/a/49633443/, https://stackoverflow.com/a/49632136/. Что-то не видно, чтобы он следовал своим же советам. Да и в исходниках книги именованные агрументы почти не встечаются. Т.е. да, в некоторых сиутациях они полезны. Но несколько странно делать из принудительными вообще везде только потому, что "Скит так в книге написал".

Comment: @ИванК нашел книгу. Нашел цитату. Она там исключительно но в контексте использования именованных аргументов в качестве альтернативы перегрузки методов. Т.е. именованные аргументы, примененные вместо добавления перегрузки, могут выглядеть непривычно. Но это не означает что их надо использовать всегда и везде :) IMHO, тесты в качестве защиты ошибки гораздо эффективнее, чем решение всегда полностью писать имя каждого параметра.

Answer (score 2):

**Если работаете с БД через Энтити, то мое решение не подойдет.**

Давайте вдарим по функциональщине - не будем удалять ничего из исходной коллекции, а просто заместим ее новой коллекцией **без ненужных** элементов:

```
var range = new List<int> {1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 6, 78, 8}; //идэшники которые нужно удалить

//коллекция из которой будем удалять, если вы под id имели в виду индекс элемента
var collection = Enumerable.Range(0, 100).ToList(); //здесь мы просто создаем коллекцию, у вас она уже есть 
collection = collection.Where((x,i)=> !range.Contains(i)).ToList(); //а вот самая мякотка здесь

//в случае если id - это поле некоторого объекта коллекции которую
//мы хотим почистить
var collection2 = Enumerable.Range(0, 100)
                            .Select(x=> new {Id = x, Value=x*10})
                            .ToList();
// то будет так:
collection2 = collection2.Where(x => !range.Contains(x.Id)).ToList();
```

В случае `Entity Framework` вроде иного способа нет:

```
db.SomeTable.RemoveRange(db.SomeTable.Where(r => IDs.Contains(r.ID)));
```

По идеи объекты в параметрах не создаются - просто все дерево транслируется в `SQL` - так что не надо беспокоится на этот счет.

Comment: collection.Except(range)

Comment: ну это только если они одного типа)

Comment: ну у вас они в примере одного типа, и индекс со значением совпадает :)

Comment: Да я простаты для)

Comment: ок. но во второй части ответа у вас написана не совсем правда - RemoveRange принимает IEnumerable, так что запрос результат запроса `db.SomeTable.Where(r => IDs.Contains(r.ID))` материализуется, EF создаст объекты для попавших под фильтр записей, и потом эти объекты через RemoveRange удалит. А у топикастера явно EF, он знает про материализацию объектов,  и поэтому в вопросе явно сказано " без создания сущностей которые требуются в RemoveRange". Так что ваш ответ на вопрос не отвечает.

Comment: В случае ef есть способ без предварительной выборки объектов из базы (с созданием фейковых объектов у которых заполнено только id).  Но объекты все равно придется создать.

Comment: @pashapash, в итоге я так и сделал, с фейковыми объектами. Оформите ответ и я его отмечу, или самому ответить себе?